# How to eliminate error message from a LocatorPane showing graphincs?

Tags: graphics, dynamic

My code

```
q1 = {{1, 0.5}, {2, 0.5}}; q2 = 10; q3 = {3, 3};
Dynamic[
  LocatorPane[Dynamic[q1],
    Graphics[{}, 
      PlotRange -> {{0, Dynamic[q2]}, {-1, 1}},
      Axes -> True], 
    Appearance -> q3], 
  TrackedSymbols :> {q3}]
```

is wrong, because when I press this button

```
Button["Add", AppendTo[q1, {q1[[-1, 1]] + 1, 0.5}]; AppendTo[q3, 1]]
```

a bad output cell appears, and I get the mesage

> The specified setting for the option GraphicsBoxOptions, PloRange cannot be used."

[image]

What is wrong here??

Comment: I don't know but if you leave `q2` without `Dynamic` it will work, also wrapping `LocatorPane` and `Button` with e.g. `Column` will prevent the error too.

Comment: as Kuba said, the problem is that you wrapped `q2` in Dynamics. Dynamics is for display only. Nothing that has Dynamics will be understood by the Kernel. only the FE` understands dynamics. So passing a Dynamics to PlotRange is not going to work. Dynamics should be an outermost wrapper, something that can be only handled by the FE' and not send to the kernel.

Comment: From what i read about Dynamic[], I should nest them to avoid the whole LocatorPane[...] expression to be reevaluated whenever q2 changes (why would that be necessary?). Not true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want is this:

```
q1 = {{1, 0.5}, {2, 0.5}}; q2 = 10; q3 = {3, 3};
Dynamic[LocatorPane[Dynamic[q1], 
  Graphics[{}, PlotRange -> Dynamic@{{0, q2}, {-1, 1}}, Axes -> True],
   Appearance -> q3], TrackedSymbols :> {q3}]
```

You can have a dynamic `PlotRange`, but you have to wrap the whole range specification with `Dynamic`.

Comment: I think there is still something missing. Try `{Dynamic[LocatorPane...] , Button[...]}` and later `Column@{Dynamic[LocatorPane[...]], Button[...]}`, with `PlotRange->{{0, Dynamic@q2},{...}}`

Comment: Something is missing? Would you please clarify, because the code seems perfectly fine to me.

Comment: I tried `Dynamic[Print[0];LocatorPane[(*Michael E2 answer, except for "TrackedSymbols:>{q3}"*)]` and found that option to be unnecessary.

Comment: @Coolwater I meant, it works but I don't understand something with the behaviour of FE here. :) This answer works ok.